# Please help me troubleshoot MacPro Kernel Panic

Tags: mac-pro, kernel-panic

I am getting a lot of Kernel Panics recently, sometimes several per day. Here is the most recent one which occured when running Pro Tools HD on my MacPr 2,1:

```
Interval Since Last Panic Report:  290582 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          11
Anonymous UUID:                    E8982051-0F07-453E-8F94-F6379BC6CA63

Fri Jan 23 00:21:59 2015
Machine-check capabilities 0x0000000000000806:
 family: 6 model: 15 stepping: 11 microcode: 0
 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5365  @ 3.00GHz
 6 error-reporting banks
 threshold-based error status present
Processor 0: no machine-check status reported
Processor 1: no machine-check status reported
Processor 2: no machine-check status reported
Processor 3: no machine-check status reported
Processor 4: machine-check status 0x0000000000000005:
 restart IP valid
 machine-check in progress
MCA error-reporting registers:
 IA32_MC0_STATUS(0x401): 0xb200004000000800 valid
  MCA error code:            0x0800
  Model specific error code: 0x0000
  Other information:         0x00000040
  Threshold-based status:    Undefined
  Status bits:
   Processor context corrupt
   Error enabled
   Uncorrected error
 IA32_MC1_STATUS(0x405): 0x0000000000000000 invalid
 IA32_MC2_STATUS(0x409): 0x0000000000000000 invalid
 IA32_MC3_STATUS(0x40d): 0x0020000000000000 invalid
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0x0000000000000011 invalid
 IA32_MC5_STATUS(0x415): 0xb200221024080400 valid
  MCA error code:            0x0400
  Model specific error code: 0x2408
  Other information:         0x00002210
  Threshold-based status:    Undefined
  Status bits:
   Processor context corrupt
   Error enabled
   Uncorrected error
Processor 5: no machine-check status reported
Processor 6: no machine-check status reported
Processor 7: no machine-check status reported
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff80098b91b9): "Machine Check at                     
0xffffff7f8b0123ce, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2:     
0x000000010fc8b000, CR3: 0x000000002e9b2000, CR4: 0x0000000000000660\n"     
"RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0xffffff802a508800, RCX:     
0x0000000000000001, RDX: 0x0000000000000000\n" "RSP: 0xffffff81dae3b9a0, 
RBP: 0xffffff81dae3b9d0, RSI: 0x0000000000000001, RDI: 
0xffffff81d091d148\n" "R8:  0x1000000000000000, R9:  0x0000000000988a00, 
R10: 0xffffff8009ef3b00, R11: 0x0000000000000246\n" "R12: 
0x0000000000000001, R13: 0xffffff802a35cac0, R14: 0x0000000000000000, R15: 
0x0000000000000148\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000046, RIP: 0xffffff7f8b0123ce, 
CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010\n" "Error code:     
0x0000000000000000\n"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-
2050.48.12/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:280
Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81d092cec0 : 0xffffff800981d636 
0xffffff81d092cf30 : 0xffffff80098b91b9 
0xffffff81d092d0a0 : 0xffffff80098cf4df 
0xffffff81dae3b9d0 : 0xffffff7f8b00b6d2 
0xffffff81dae3bab0 : 0xffffff7f8b00aa6e 
0xffffff81dae3bb60 : 0xffffff80098ba19a 
0xffffff81dae3bb80 : 0xffffff800982f35d 
0xffffff81dae3bbc0 : 0xffffff800982de11 
0xffffff81dae3bc20 : 0xffffff800982db83 
0xffffff81dae3bc60 : 0xffffff80098342f7 
0xffffff81dae3bcc0 : 0xffffff7f8a6b671e 
0xffffff81dae3bcf0 : 0xffffff7f8a6b69a5 
0xffffff81dae3bd20 : 0xffffff8009927806 
0xffffff81dae3bd70 : 0xffffff80099190e4 
0xffffff81dae3bde0 : 0xffffff800990f509 
0xffffff81dae3be30 : 0xffffff8009b52f83 
0xffffff81dae3be60 : 0xffffff8009b7fa23 
0xffffff81dae3bf60 : 0xffffff8009be94c3 
0xffffff81dae3bfb0 : 0xffffff80098cf130 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement(214.0)[3B20B0E5-    
0D48-36D9-BA2C-B6208BC6E795]@0xffffff7f8b008000->0xffffff7f8b035fff
         com.digidesign.iokit.DigiDal(10.3.8f123)[07139795-3C93-8119-8513-
2884210177D9]@0xffffff7f8a6aa000->0xffffff7f8a6e9fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[6C1D646D-7E5E-
3D7F-A557-2CBA398FF878]@0xffffff7f89e08000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Pro Tools
Boot args:  kext-dev-mode=1 -v

Mac OS version:
12F45

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 12.5.0: Sun Sep 29 13:33:47 PDT 2013; root:xnu-    
2050.48.12~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: EA38B02E-2B88-309F-BA68-1DE29F605DD8
Kernel slide:     0x0000000009600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8009800000
System model name: MacPro2,1 (Mac-F4208DC8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 1461343421554
last loaded kext at 1309568223737: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs  1.8.4 
(addr 0xffffff7f8b85e000, size 229376)
last unloaded kext at 308132683319: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.8.1 
(addr 0xffffff7f8b850000, size 57344)
loaded kexts:
com.paceap.kext.pacesupport.snowleopard 5.9.1
com.kensington.trackballworks.driver    1.2.0
com.digidesign.iokit.DigiDal    10.3.8f123
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.8.4
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.1.7f4
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.4.7fc4
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.12
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.11
com.apple.driver.AppleMCEDriver 1.1.9
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   8.1.6
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.3
com.apple.AMDRadeonAccelerator  1.0.8
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.4.5
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.5.6
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    635.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIntel8254XEthernet    3.1.1b1
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.9
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.6.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   621.4.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPIIXATA  2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   621.4.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 34
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 214.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   4.0.39
com.apple.security.quarantine   2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   214.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.6
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.4.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.2fc7
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.12
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   86.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.1.7f4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.4.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.4.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 74.17
com.apple.kext.AMD7000Controller    8.1.6
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   8.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.4.5
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.7
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.0d5
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.4.1d13    
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHIDKeyboard    170.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   170.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  623.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   621.4.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  621.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOATAPIProtocolTransport    3.5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.5.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 630.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOATAFamily 2.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 635.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  220.3
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 345
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.21
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.8
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacPro2,1, BootROM MP21.007F.B06, 8 processors, Quad-Core Intel     
Xeon, 3 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 1.7f10
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 7950, AMD Radeon HD 7950, PCIe, 3072 MB
Memory Module: DIMM Riser A/DIMM 1, 2 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x0198,     
0x4B494E4753544F4E00000000000000000000
Memory Module: DIMM Riser A/DIMM 2, 2 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x0198, 
0x4B494E4753544F4E00000000000000000000
Memory Module: DIMM Riser B/DIMM 1, 2 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x0198, 
0x4B494E4753544F4E00000000000000000000
Memory Module: DIMM Riser B/DIMM 2, 2 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x0198, 
0x4B494E4753544F4E00000000000000000000
Memory Module: DIMM Riser A/DIMM 3, 2 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x0198, 
0x4B494E4753544F4E20202020202020202020
Memory Module: DIMM Riser A/DIMM 4, 2 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x0198, 
0x4B494E4753544F4E20202020202020202020
Memory Module: DIMM Riser B/DIMM 3, 2 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x0198, 
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000
Memory Module: DIMM Riser B/DIMM 4, 2 GB, DDR2 FB-DIMM, 667 MHz, 0x0198, 
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000
Network Service: Ethernet 1, Ethernet, en0
PCI Card: AMD Radeon HD 7950, sppci_displaycontroller, Slot-1
PCI Card: AMD Radeon HD 7950, ATY,HamachiParent, Slot-1
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@8,4,0
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@6,4,0
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@8,5,0
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@8,6,0
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@6,5,0
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@6,6,0
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@10,4,0
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@16,4,0
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@18,4,0
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@16,5,0
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@10,5,0
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@18,5,0
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@14,4,0
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@16,6,0
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@10,6,0
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@18,6,0
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@12,4,0
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@14,5,0
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@12,5,0
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@12,6,0
PCI Card: pci1057,3410, sppci_othermultimedia, Slot-4@14,6,0
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 840 EVO 250GB, 250.06 GB
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HDS722020ALA330, 2 TB
Serial ATA Device: WDC WD20EARX-00PASB0, 2 TB
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HDS722020ALA330, 2 TB
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 840 EVO 120GB, 120.03 GB
Serial ATA Device: WDC WD3000HLFS-01G6U0, 300.07 GB
Parallel ATA Device: _NEC DVD_RW ND-4570A
USB Device: USB 2.0 Hub [MTT], 0x1a40  (TERMINUS TECHNOLOGY INC.), 0x0101, 
0xfd400000 / 3
USB Device: MT4, 0x086a  (Emagic Soft-und Hardware Gmbh), 0x0003, 
0xfd440000 / 8
USB Device: CTH-470, 0x056a  (WACOM Co., Ltd.), 0x00de, 0xfd430000 / 7
USB Device: Keyboard Hub, apple_vendor_id, 0x1006, 0xfd420000 / 6
USB Device: Kensington Expert Mouse, 0x047d  (Kensington), 0x1020, 
0xfd423000 / 10
USB Device: Apple Keyboard, apple_vendor_id, 0x0250, 0xfd422000 / 9
USB Device: hub_device, 0x050d  (Belkin Corporation), 0x0237, 0xfd300000 / 
2
USB Device: iLok, 0x088e, 0x5036, 0xfd370000 / 5
USB Device: iLok, 0x088e, 0x5036, 0xfd360000 / 4
FireWire Device: built-in_hub, 800mbit_speed
```

I have done MemTest and the RAM is apparently ok. My machine is an upgraded MacPro 1,1 with X5365's and a flashed AMD7950 running 10.8.5. I have an expansion chassis connected with the host card in slot 4.

Really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: kext backtrace shows AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement on the top and google has plenty of results about AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement crashes. In short, try to reset SMC and see if anything changes.

Comment: @Rilakkuma: I had already done the reset but noticed I was getting the following error on a fresh install of 10.8:`kernel[0]: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR: smcReadData8 failed for key BEMB (kSMCKeyNotFound)`  which I managed to get rid off by replacing the ML AppleSMC.kext (3.1.5) with the one from Snow Leopard (3.1.0). After that I did not reset SMC again which I have done now and am testing.

Comment: How far out of date is your Pace & digidesign? I've known old Pace to push things over, but I don't use protools so idk about that, I'm cubendo mainly.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this thread via a Google search, I have found and eliminated the cause of the kernel panics.

The problem was a failing PSU, both, inside the MacPro as well as the Magma expansion chassis. See [here](http://duc.avid.com/showpost.php?p=2246050&postcount=3) for details:

I have since built a Hackintosh and have not had any further problems with intermittent kernel panics.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Some years ago I had the problem of frequent kernel panics with my Mac Pro 1,1 ... it turned out that the inside of the case had lots of dust.  When I cleared that out, the kernel panics stopped.

I'm sure every case is different.  This may not help you, but I will put it here for future people who have this problem.